# Go tools を揃えると Ruby の Bundler と名前が被る

Tags: ruby, go, bundler

Go をインストールしたら最初に `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/...` をして `gorename` や `goimports` などエディタが静的解析等で使うであろうツールを一括でインストールしていました。

最近 Ruby を使いはじめて、これだと golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle と Ruby の Bundler のコマンド名がどちらも `bundle` になっていて被ると気づきました。Go 側の issue によるとこれを直すつもりは無いようです: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23700 。私の環境の PATH は `$GOPATH/bin` の方が先頭に入っているため、`bundle` コマンドで Go の bundle が呼ばれてしまい困ります。

PATH の順番を弄ったり Go tools を一括インストールするのではなく個別にしたりする解決法もありますが、やや面倒に思っています。（PATH は他のツールとの兼ね合いもあり……。）

Go の bundle は当面のところ使わないので、良い感じに Ruby の Bundler を使えるようにする方法は無いでしょうか。

環境: macOS Catalina

<sub>※自己回答していますが、環境構築するにあたってもっと便利な方法があれば知りたいです。</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Go tools を一括インストールした後、bundle だけアンインストールするのでとりあえず問題なさそうでした。

```sh
go clean -i golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

[direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) を用いると、「特定のディレクトリだけで有効な PATH の prepend」を実現できそうです。

具体例: `.envrc` にて、

```
PATH_add "/path/to/bin/dir"
```

この `.envrc` ですと、

1. そのディレクトリに cd したら PATH に prepend される
2. そのディレクトリから cd して他の場所に移動すると、 prepend が解除される

何がどうなって上記が実現できているのかは、私はちょっと把握できていないです。

さらに `.envrc` はただのシェル実行ファイルですので、任意に整理ができそうな雰囲気はあります。